# Intuition for the Liouville one-form restricted to the unit cotangent-bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, contact-geometry

So, it seems to be a fairly classical result that the Liouville one-form restricts to the unit cotangent bundle of a Riemann surface equipped with a Riemannian metric. I know that the flow of Reeb vector field is then geodesic flow but I can't seem get a "feel" for the Liouville form. In the case of the unit cotangent bundle of $S^2$, for intstance, is there some set of coordinates that will help me see this one-form better? Or something wordy someone can say to help me understand?

Comment: If you march around in a Riemannian manifold, carrying a spear in your hands, Liouville is how your velocity correlates that spear, giving 1 when you head in the direction your spear points, -1 when you head in the opposite direction, zero when you move perpendicular to your spear's direction.